# how to check mysql for duplicates with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, duplicates

I need a way to check a database if a word is in it already if so then it doesn't have to be pushed to the database if the word isn't in it yet then it has to be  pushed into it.
It's a MYSQL database and I have to do it in PHP this is what I got so far.

```
$result = array_count_values(explode(" ", $filter));
arsort($result);
foreach ($result as $word => $frequency)
{
    if (!in_array($word, [" ", ""]))
        query("words", "INSERT INTO Woord (woord) VALUE (?)",[$word], false);
}
query("words" "SELECT WHERE")
```

Comment: Add a unique constraint on the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**REPLACE**

```
REPLACE INTO table
SET column = 'example'
```

This will overwrite if the record exists and if not it will create it.

**INSERT IGNORE**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table
SET column = 'example'
```

This will ignore the query if already exists and if not it will create it.

Your php query should look like this:

`"INSERT IGNORE INTO ID142118_ascii.Woord (woord) VALUES (".$word.")"`

Comment: hi thanks for you quick response how would this look into my code?

Comment: I've edited my post, please accept the answer if it suits for you.

Comment: and this piece of query would come instead of  the part with query("words" "SELECT WHERE")

Comment: I don't understand your code, but let me make this simple: iterate through your words and for every $word run the query and if the word already exists it will not add it to the database else it should add it to the database.

Comment: After some testing I see that I still get error's in my database that it doesn't want to skip the words that are already in the database

Comment: That is because you did not make the column Woord unique or a primary key. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

put a unique constraint on the column "woord" in the table.
Then you can let your php script insert as many duplicate words as you want to, it will simply fail.

you could either add a part "ignore duplicate" in your query or just ignore the error you will get.

I thinks that will be easiest to do.

edit:
btw I can think of a lot of words containing serveral of the character you are stripping: "foto's", "zee-eend" etc

--

how to make a unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE asciiwoorden
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX somename (Woord);
```